# SoundCloud JS SDK: Volume slider doesn't work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, soundcloud

I'm having an issue where I am using soundcloud API to work on an embedded playlist on my website, when I try to use my volume slider it doesn't change the volume in iOS devices.
Here's how I initialized the code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud'));
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
console.log('Ready...');
    });

var volumeControl = document.getElementById('vol-control');
widget.setVolume(7.5);
var setVolumne = function() { widget.setVolume((this.value)/10);     console.log(this.value);};

volumeControl.addEventListener('change', setVolumne);
volumeControl.addEventListener('input', setVolumne);
   });
```

The volume levels were set from 0-1 (They have not updated their documentation) but still no changes in volume. Though it works on android and PC. Here's the demo page [here](http://www.awesomex.tk/www.spotebi.com/wp-content/gif-timer/make-timer.html). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the knowledge that volume control is not possible through SoundCloud API for IOS(upto 9) devices because of their restrictions(iphone's), just letting you people know so that you don't waste your time like me. I'll provide the sources(of information) later if I can.